# Resize a group of paths in a svg file

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm wondering if I can animate a group of paths directly in the svg file?

I have a complex svg file and I would like to scale only one part, which I wrapped in the `<g>` element.

I tried something like this, but nothing happen.

```html
<g id="Fire">
      <path/>
      <circle/>
      <path fill="#FEC33A" d="M216.562,546.14c-0.13-0.38-0.26-0.75-0.4-1.12C216.302,545.38,216.442,545.76,216.562,546.14z"/>
      <path fill="#F27D16" d="M215.032,573.37c-0.15-0.19-0.3-0.37-0.46-0.54C214.742,573.01,214.892,573.19,215.032,573.37z"/>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="scale"
                          from="1"
                          to="1.1"
                          dur="2s"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SMIL animations you may put the group in a `<defs>` element and reuse it with `<use>`. Then you may animate the use element

```css
svg{border:1px solid; overflow:visible}
path{stroke:black;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="210 540 15 40" width="100">
<defs>
  <g id="Fire">
      <path  d="M216.562,546.14
                c-0.13-0.38-0.26-0.75-0.4-1.12C216.302,545.38,216.442,545.76,216.562,546.14z">
        
        
  </path>
      <path d="M215.032,573.37c-0.15-0.19-0.3-0.37-0.46-0.54C214.742,573.01,214.892,573.19,215.032,573.37z"/>
 
</g>
  </defs> 
  
  <use xlink:href="#Fire" >
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="scale"
                          from="1"
                          to="1.1"
                          dur="2s"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
  
</svg>
```

**PS** I suppose you may have a reason to use such complicated paths instead of a line

Comment: I made it with adobe illustrator maybe that's why there are complicated paths.

Basically, your code works. I mean the animation affect the group.

However, the group doesn't scale, the animation acts more like a translation.